# Area51 visit/day and total users statistics are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, statistics, beta-sites

Bi-weekly I help with writing down the Area51 statistics of 2 beta websites in [this Meta Sustainability SE post](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/site-statistics) and [this Meta Martial Arts SE post](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/keeping-track-of-our-statistics). We do this so all site users can monitor growth of these sites.

Today I noticed that both the 'visits/day' and the 'total users' statistic in Area51 did not change for both sites since at least May 15, which seems very unlikely especially when it happens to 2 sites at the same time. Also the statistics in the 'site stats' box on the homepage of both sites show different visit/day and users numbers than Area51, so it seems new statistics are being generated but just not updated on Area51.

A quick look at other beta websites like Genealogy, Gardening, Politics and DevOps shows that for all the 'total user' Area51 stat lags behind the one reported in the homepage 'site stats' box, so all Area51 beta-site pages are probably affected by this bug.

Comment: I thought our visits/day at [genealogy.se] seemed lower than my perception lately.

Comment: @PolyGeo https://widget.quantcast.com/user/widgetImage?domain=genealogy.stackexchange.com&widget=10&timeWidth=1&daysOfData=7 shows between 885 and 1195 visits/day in the last week, so I guess the 1079 visits/day on your home page is fine. However the 6,060 total users reported [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history) is inconsistent with the 6,118 reported on your home page

Comment: Oops - I was reading "visits/day" as "questions/day".  It's the latter that I think seems frozen for the last week or so.

Comment: It could be that questions/day is also frozen, but that's harder to determine. Unlike visits/day and total users it's not uncommon for the q/day statistic to remain the same for 1 or 2 weeks (at least not in the 2 sites I monitor).

Comment: Questions/day has been the same value on Writing for at least the last week.  While it's probably in the right *ballpark* (based on the site analytics), it seems unlikely that it would stay *exactly* the same, down to the decimal point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had to make changes to the Google Analytics API keys we use, and kind of forgot about Area 51 there. It should be up to date again, though. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 1):

On [Language Learning Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) the site statistics have not been updated since 14 May. The following values have remained unchanged:

- Questions per day (1.3)
- Total users (4840, versus 4,879 according to the site's home page)
- Avid users (i.e. 200+ reps)
- Users with 2000+ reps
- Users with 3000+ reps
- Answer ratio (1.9; this has been stable for a long time)
- Visits per day

The questions per day, the number of total users and the number of visits per day have definitely not been updated. (The other stats change a lot more slowly on that site. I have been tracking these data in a spreadsheet since October 2016.) The number of days in public beta is still being updated. Everything below "Visit the site now!" is also being updated daily.

On [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) there is also a discrepancy between the number of users according to Area 51 (4,968) and the number on the home page (5,025). The number of questions per day has been stuck at 2 for some time now.

**Update 30.05.2019**: Apparently, the issue has been solved (at least on Language Learning Stack Exchange and Literature Stack Exchange).