# Why is Area 51 showing the Stack Overflow logo on Site Stats?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, beta-sites, logo

We see site stats on the home page of beta sites. Below the site stats, we have two more options to show the stats in detail.

1. Area 51
2. [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)

[image]

Previously, the Area 51 showed a Area 51 logo beside its name. But now, the Stack Overflow logo is being shown. I didn't notice this before. Is this showing up since the [previous bug repair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328872/357396)?  Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: Is Stack Overflow finally going to go through the Area 51 process?

Comment: Yeah the image source is https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d.

Comment: Also: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va9WW.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should correct itself within the next hour as cache expires.  We have logic where if we don't specify a content folder for a site, it uses the site type to select the folder.  Unfortunately, new logic was inserted above that which checks a new database location for the folder and if that fails sets it to `stackoverflow`, killing the rest of that logic.

I've explicitly set the value for Area 51 to `area51` and am submitting a proper code fix.